# Objective c operations with variables

Tags: objective-c, parsing

Is there a relatively easy way to use mathematical operators with string variables in Objective C?

For example:

The string "x*x" should return "x^2"

The string "x/x" should return "1"

I'm looking for something that would actually use the variable name "x" without an assigned numerical value and return an answer in terms of "x".

Comment: You need a math parser framework, take a look at [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) or [GCMathParser](http://apptree.net/parser.htm) ...

Comment: Even this wont do the requirement

Comment: How complicated does it need to be? Does it just need to handle polynomials with real co-efficients? If so, it wouldn't take too long to knock up something quite basic.

Comment: Or you may need to write lex and yacc parser yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the 'x' value as string then you can evaluate it as :

```
NSString *string=@"3*3";
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:string];
float result = [[expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] floatValue];
NSLog(@"%f", result);
```

Also,

```
NSString *string=@"34*(2.56+1.79)-42/1.5";
NSNumber *result=[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:string];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Change to any datatype `float` to `int` etc as per your requirement

Comment: this would only work for when x = a number in my example, im looking for something that would actually use the variable name "x" without an assigned numerical value and return an answer in terms of "x"

Comment: This is cool and I didn't know it existed but I think the OP is intending to use variables (like `"x"`). Would this support transforming `"x+x+y"` into `"2*x+y"` for example?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: Then surely a person of DaveDeLong is the best to answer. OP: you can check with DDMathParser, but I dont think even that will help you.

Comment: @user2303367:Do you need a algebraic expression kind of thing?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: I need it to simplify a string expression using algebraic logic. So if my string is "x*x*x*y*x^2/x", I need a return of "x^4*y". I took a look at DDMathParser but I believe it only supports variable operation when you assign a numerical value to the variable?

Comment: Who is the DOwnvoter(Silent no comment) for me and i guess he upvoted other answer, even DDMathParser will not work for strings....

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look for an Objective C lib doing algebraic manipulation and haven't found much yet.

So your best bet might be to use a C library (Objective C is a superset of ANSI C, after all, and you can mix the the two).

Check out this list of C maths libs:

http://www.mathtools.net/C_C__/Mathematics/

From that list, it seems that [Mathomatic](http://mathomatic.org/) might be of use.

**Two strategies for using a C library in your Objective C:**

1. Just call the C functions from your Objective C code
2. Create an Objective C wrapper for the C library and use that (and maybe release it for others to use :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see GiNaC library (www.ginac.de). It is opensource math library. You can simplify algebraic expressions with this library. And also you can compile it on OSX and link it into your Xcode project like a static C++ library.
1. You need to download Ginac, CLN and Pkg-Config (http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/). 
2. Unpack and compile Pkg-Config in your /usr/local directory
3. Unpack and compile CLN
4. Unpack and compile Ginac

Then go to you Project settings in Xcode chose your target and put your headers files path to the Header Search Path in Build Settings.
Then go to Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries click "+" and chose Add Other, then choose your compiled library file libginac.a
Thats all i think.
Dont forget to include your ginac.h file into your class header file.

```
#include <ginac.h>
```